# AWS DynamoDB in typescript: No response or error when trying to insert item

Tags: typescript, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I'm setting up a node.js server in Typescript and I have a DynamoDB on AWS, all I need to do is create/update items with 'put' and retrieve with them with 'get'.

I've made a test server in pure javascript, and everything works fine, but when I try to the exact same operation in Typescript, the callback doesn't get called, and I don't get any errors in the console.

```js
import { DynamoDB } from 'aws-sdk'

const client = new DynamoDB.DocumentClient({ region: 'eu-west-3'})
const params = {
  TableName: "Movies",
  Item: {
    "primary": "foo",
    "range": 123,
    "text": "bar"
  }
}

client.put(params, (err, data) => {
  console.log('done')
})
```

Compiled Javascript:

```js
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
const aws_sdk_1 = require("aws-sdk");
const client = new aws_sdk_1.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
const params = {
    TableName: "Movies",
    Item: {
        "primary": "foo",
        "range": 123,
        "text": "bar"
    }
};
client.put(params).promise().then(res => console.log(res)).catch(err => console.log(err)).finally(() => console.log('finally'));
//# sourceMappingURL=app.js.map
```

Comment: dumb question here....did you compile the TS and run the js file it creates?

Comment: @LostJon I compile with the 'tsc' command then run the generated .js file with 'node dist/app.js'

Comment: your code looks good....im kinda surprised `console.log` doesnt get hit and no errors are thrown. if you put a `console.log` anywhere, does it log out?

Comment: @LostJon If I put ```console.log``` anywhere outside of the put callback it'll log out to the console.

Comment: @LostJon I tried
```client.put(params).promise().then(res => console.log(res)).catch(err => console.log(err)).finally(() => console.log('finally'))```
still nothing

Comment: you sending output to `/dev/null`?! jk..can post what the transpiled JS looks like?

Comment: Try importing DDB this way:
`import DynamoDB from 'aws-sdk/clients/dynamodb';`....really grasping here

Comment: @LostJon Well, this is embarrassing, under the code I had a ton on comments, but I had left ```process.exit(0)``` uncommented. Obviously once that was deleted, it all worked.